# Where does the formula from the hypergeometric distribution come from?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

In a box are $M$ blue balls and $N$ green balls. We take $n$ balls without putting them back.

Let $X$ be the variable "# blue balls that were taken".

Then $$P\{X = k\} = \frac{\binom{M}{k}\binom{N}{n-k}}{\binom{M+N}{n}}$$

Where does this formula come from?

The textbook then says that $X$ is hypergeometrically distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the ratio of the count of ways to select $k$ from $M$ things(eg blue balls) *and* $n-k$ from $N$ things(eg green balls) to the count of ways to select any $n$ from $M+N$ things(ie all balls); when such selections are made without bias or replacement.

Recollect: $\binom x y$ is the count of ways to select $y$ elements from a set of size $x$, when selecting without replacement.

Comment: Dear Teacher, dear Professor, I'm so sorry for this comment...I asked the question mathoverflow for help. But the question was downvoted. I had to delete the question.Now, if I ask in MSE , I know that, the question again will be downvoted. I really need help. But unfortunately, no one helped. If I ask you for help, can you take a look? If you have a few minutes. Then, I will delete this comment..I am very happy if you comment here alone. Because the question is already going to close..Thank you very much...  https://mathoverflow.net/q/298997/123863

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{M+N}{n}$ is the number of ways to draw $n$ balls from a collection of $M+N$ (blue or green) balls.

$\binom{M}{k}$ is the number of ways to draw $k$ balls from $M$ blue balls. We drew $n$ balls, so we must have drawn $n-k$ green balls. Hence we multiply this quantity by $\binom{N}{n-k}$ to find the number of ways to draw $k$ blue balls and $n-k$ green balls.